# Как подсчитать количество записей в категории по условию?

Tags: sql, mysql

Есть такой запрос:

```
SELECT
  idSpecialization,
  thematicspecialization.SpecializationName AS SpecializationName,
  SubscrubeToUsersIdNote,
  COUNT(question_categoryId) AS CNT,
  COUNT(idSubscrubeToUsers) AS SUBS
FROM thematicspecialization
LEFT JOIN question_category
  ON question_category.question_categoryIdCategory = thematicspecialization.idSpecialization
LEFT JOIN question a
  ON a.idQuestion = question_category.question_categoryIdQuestion
LEFT JOIN subscrubetousers
  ON (subscrubetousers.SubscrubeToUsersIdNote = idSpecialization
  AND subscrubetousers.SubscrubeToUsersType = 4
  AND SubscrubeToUsersStatus = 1) 
WHERE a.country = 1
GROUP BY idSpecialization
```

Нужно всегда выводить названия категорий из `thematicspecialization` с условием WHERE `a.country = 1` для соединения таблиц `question a ON a.idQuestion = question_category.question_categoryIdQuestion`

В моем случае - категории не выводятся.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте группировку по категории.